# Firefox Addon SDK message passing error

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Im trying to pass messages between a pageMod and a content script.

I use this code with the pageMod

```
var gmailPageMod = pageMod.PageMod({
            include: "https://mail.google.com/*",
            contentScriptWhen: "ready",
            contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('js/script.js')],
            contentStyleFile: [
                self.data.url("css/angular.min.css"),
                self.data.url("css/style.css")
            ],
            onAttach: function(worker) {
                try {
                    console.log("adding worker");
                    gmail_workers.push(worker);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("error", error);
                }

                worker.port.on("getTalentGamil_recipient_change", function(email) {
                    console.log(email);
                });
                try {
                    console.log("updating SS");
                    console.log(simpleStorage);
                    worker.port.emit("updateSimpleStorage", simpleStorage);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("error", error);
                }

            });
```

and in script.js

```
self.port.on("updateSimpleStorage", function(simpleStorage) {
    console.log('updateSimpleStorage from script.js', simpleStorage);
    var e = new CustomEvent('updateSimpleStorage', {
        'detail': simpleStorage
    });
    window.dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

However this gives me an error `Message: [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0"  data: no]`

I dont understand why though? Because I think Im doing exactly whats being done [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). I'd appreciate any help on the matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1045943) and according to it, `CustomEvents` no longer work, so I used a roundabout message passing route with FF Addon SDK's native messaging to get my info across.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#Accessing_port_in_the_Add-on_Script

So you are emitting from main.js this:

```
worker.port.emit("updateSimpleStorage", simpleStorage);
```

And you are wondering why its not calling the callback in `script.js` right?

Here are my thoughts on possible issues:

1. Is there maybe a chance that the `contentScript` of script.js has not loaded yet?
2. What is `simpleStorage`? Is it serializ-able?

If script.js has not loaded, I would recommend trying this:

In `main.js` in `onAttach` listen for a load event like this:

```
var gmailPageMod = pageMod.PageMod({
            include: "https://mail.google.com/*",
            contentScriptWhen: "ready",
            contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('js/script.js')],
            contentStyleFile: [
                self.data.url("css/angular.min.css"),
                self.data.url("css/style.css")
            ],
            onAttach: function(worker) {
                try {
                    console.log("adding worker");
                    gmail_workers.push(worker);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("error", error);
                }

                worker.port.on("getTalentGamil_recipient_change", function(email) {
                    console.log(email);
                });

                worker.port.on('iLoaded', function() {
                    try {
                        console.log("updating SS");
                        console.log(simpleStorage);
                        worker.port.emit("updateSimpleStorage", simpleStorage);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log("error", error);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Notice how I wrapped it in a `iLoaded`.

Then in `script.js` emit the `iLoaded` message like this:

```
self.port.on("updateSimpleStorage", function(simpleStorage) {
    console.log('updateSimpleStorage from script.js', simpleStorage);
    var e = new CustomEvent('updateSimpleStorage', {
        'detail': simpleStorage
    });
    window.dispatchEvent(e);
});

self.port.emit('iLoaded');
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. However, the issue wasnt the FF native messaging. It was the `CustomEvent`, apparently its been deprecated and no longer works with FF 42.

Comment: Thats interesting @Irtza.QC can you please link the source. And also post and accept your solution please.